# ExtJs property grid - Selected rows editable?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm using a property grid with editors set in sourceConfig. I want only some rows to be editable and not all. Returning false in `beforeedit` disables all. The reason is, I have a button in a grid. When I click the button, the grid turns to a textfield! Any way to do this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Could you post a Fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeedit` event should provide you with the editor and the editing context. Lets say your callback function looks like this:

```
function(editor,context) { ... }
```

Using the context you will get the record which get edited by accessing `context.record` while the editor can provide you with the editor form from where you have access to all rendered fields within that form. To get the form you have to get the editor first and after that you can fetch the form

```
var form = editor.getEditor().getForm()
```

This way you can be sure that the editor has been set up. To get a field within that form simply call

```
form.findField('fieldname') // fieldname is the dataIndex of the column
```

You can now do nearly anything based on your conditions.

In addition the record is also loaded into this form an can be accessed by calling `form.getRecord()`